# Import single element from different website by ID

Tags: html, import, web

i would like to import a specific element from another website to my website. 
For example, i'd like to import this:

```
<div id="mainbar-full">
...
</div>
```

from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) website to *foo.stackoverflow.com/bar* .
This should be like an iframe, not showing the whole page but a part of it.

Is it possible to do this?

-Cerdo

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an iframe, it is not a particularly clean solution but I cannot think of any other way of doing it.

You wont be able to use a stackoverflow page as stackoverflow have their website set to only allow same domain iframe requests, but just so you understand I will use it in my example.

Here is an example using the ID and URL you mentioned:

```
<iframe src="http://stackoverflow.com/tour/#mainbar-full" scrolling="no" class="iframe"></iframe>
```

You would then need to set the following CSS to get the whole contents:

```
.iframe {
    height: 4555px;
    width: 980px;
    overflow: none;
}
```

This would show the entire contents of that element on the page.

As i said above, this does not feel like a very clean solution but its all I can think of at the moment.

Here is a working example with buzzfeed: http://jsfiddle.net/kyZzk/

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery and `load();` method like this:

This code in your page on your host

```
<div id="main_bar">
```

//............some thing ....... 
   //..........................

```
</div>
```

This code in your current page

```
$("selector").load("http://www.yourdomin.com/page.php#mainbar");
```